# CentOS HTTPD and MySql dont want to start

Tags: mysql, apache, centos

I'm using VestaCP for a week now and i asked this error on the forum but they dont react to my topic so i'll ask it here.

Apache and MySql wont start.
If i type: /bin/systemctl status httpd.service i get this

```
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2016-04-19 19:04:53 CEST; 10s ago
  Process: 4447 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 4446 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 4446 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 19 19:04:53 main-vps-centos httpd[4446]: (98)Address already in use: AH0...0
Apr 19 19:04:53 main-vps-centos httpd[4446]: (98)Address already in use: AH0...0
Apr 19 19:04:53 main-vps-centos httpd[4446]: no listening sockets available,...n
Apr 19 19:04:53 main-vps-centos httpd[4446]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Apr 19 19:04:53 main-vps-centos systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exit...E
Apr 19 19:04:53 main-vps-centos kill[4447]: kill: cannot find process ""
Apr 19 19:04:53 main-vps-centos systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process e...1
Apr 19 19:04:53 main-vps-centos systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP ....
Apr 19 19:04:53 main-vps-centos systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered faile....
Apr 19 19:04:53 main-vps-centos systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

What i tryed:
"Yum Remove httpd mysql mysql-server mariadb" then "Yum install httpd mysql mysql-server mariadb" but it doenst work.

Help!

Comment: can you post the extract from `/var/log/messages` the 'address already in use' sounds like your trying to bind to something wrong, or its already running. is this a live box or a test/dev? also what was the error when you tried to `yum remove` and `yum install`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `httpd` port is already used by some process.
Are your VestaCP working at the same 80 port as Apache?
If so, you can't run httpd service until change it to some other port as well.

You should also try `netstat -lptu` to find out what process is using the port first.

Comment: Well your HTTP port is occupied by nginx instance